# How to post variables in ASPX?

Tags: asp.net

In an ASPX page, I am populating the rows of a table programatically by filling up a server-side string with  contents and then putting it in the output HTML with a construct `<tbody><%=mystring%></tbody>`.

One of the `<td>` elements of the row is a button to delete the row, and I need to pass to the server another `<td>` element in the row.

In the server-side code that prepares the table, I tried with:

```
string RowTemplate; 
RowTemplate = "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td><form action=\"/submit\" name=\"removeemail{0}\" runat=\"server\"><input custom=\"{1}\" class=\"btn icon-remove\" value=\"X\" onserverclick=\"RemoveEmail\" runat=\"server\"/></form></td></tr>";
```

Then, as I create rows, the place holders {0}, {1}, and {2} are replaced by the row's corresponding values.

The idea is to retrieve the "custom" attribute (the key for deletion) at the server-side function called RemoveEmail, and then build the table again without the removed row.

However, it seems that the generated HTML for this inline form is not preprocessed by ASPX engine so HTML code that reaches the browser is directly the ASPX HTML markup.

How could I have the ASPX markup preprocessed so that it behaves exactly as static ASPX markup like the one that is find an a .aspx file?  If that is not possible, how could I manage server-side deletion with an inline button on a table row in ASPX?

Comment: The answer here will vary wildly depending on whether you use web forms or mvc, but either way it looks like you're doing this hard way by trying to build your table as a string.

Comment: Good point. I went ahead and added an answer with forms' code without thinking for a second whether this was mvc or forms :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that by adding `runat="server"` to these `HTML Controls` will make them work as server side controls. You can add `runat="server"` to the markup, and that would work. This is one way I would do this:

Markup:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tbl"></asp:Table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code Behind:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Argument0" });
tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Argument1" });
tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Argument2" });
TableCell td = new TableCell();
Button btn = new Button();

tr.Cells.Add(td);
btn.Text = "Remove Email";
btn.Click+=new EventHandler(removeEmail);

td.Controls.Add(btn);
this.tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

void removeEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //code here
}
```

This adds  the `Button` control to a `TableCell`, and attaches the `removeEmail()` event to this button.

Good luck.

Comment: This approach seems to work pretty well, except that I do not seem to have the ability to set the <thead> values. For some reason, I do not seem to be able to create a TableHeaderRow object even when I am using System.Web.UI.WebControls. I tried with using System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableHeaderRow, but it does not find that. Any ideas on how I could add a table header row with this approach?

Comment: Do you get any exception when you try to use a TableHeaderRow? I can definitely see it in my project.

Comment: It simply says that the object is not found, but looking at the docs, it mentions that it is new in 2.0, but I found out that the server I am using resolves <%=Environment.Version%> as 1.1.4322.2500, so it needs to be upgraded for the TableHeaderRow object to exist at all.